# Finding density of a non symmetric function

Tags: calculus, probability

I have completed several transformation questions using change of variables and the Jacobian.  I would like to understand how to answer the following :

> If $Y$ is Uniform $[-1, 3]$, find the density of $2Y^2-1$.